# Проблема с версией .net core

Tags: .net, .net-core

Как решаются подобные проблемы? есть проект на .net core 2.2.105
у меня стоит 2017 студия и 2.2.203
при запуске проекты появляется следующая ошибка [image: ю]

Почему она выпадает?

Comment: Пробовали ли сделать то, что написано? Т.е., установить .net core SDK версии 2.2

Comment: стоит же 2.2.203..на скриншоте слева вверху

Comment: Примерно так решаются: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513335/the-current-net-sdk-does-not-support-targeting-net-core-2-2-sdk-2-2-202

Comment: v2.2.203 несовместим с VS2017 похоже. Попробуйте поставить более старый отсюда: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2